# How to return or pass output outside of javascript ElasticSearch APIs

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm not familiar with javascript, so I need a help. 
I'd like to pull documents from ElasticSearch and then, visualize the results on google geochart. 
My question is how a function, drawMarkersMap() can get 'rows' calculated in "function(body)"

```
client.search({
    "index": "indexname",
    "type": "typename",
    "size": 100,
    body: { 
        "query": {
           "match_all": {}
        }
    }
}).then(function(body) {
    var rows = [];  
    var results = body.hits.hits;
    for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ... // parsing data and 
        cols=['a', 'b', 'c']; // example row
        rows[i] = cols;          
    }        
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

function drawMarkersMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);
    ...
    google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're almost there, when you're done parsing your results, you simply need to call `drawMarkersMap()` and pass the rows in argument to that function, like this:

```
...
}).then(function(body) {
    var rows = [];  
    var results = body.hits.hits;
    for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ... // parsing data and 
        cols=['a', 'b', 'c']; // example row
        rows[i] = cols;     

        drawMarkersMap(rows);         <---- call draw and pass your rows here     
    }        
}, function (error) {
...
});

function drawMarkersMap(rows) {       <---- add rows parameter here
...
}
```